# Statistics in GridDB using TQL

Tags: griddb

Is there a built-in library or function to calculate statistics (i.e., mean, median, mode, etc.) in GridDB using TQL?

P.S. I did not find any command in the GridDB Documentation. The link to the documentation is attached below.

Reference: https://docs.griddb.net/sqlreference/sql-commands-supported/#data-definition-language-ddl